# using a function within a component that gets removed - state transition warning

Tags: reactjs

This application works. I don't see any problems in performance, but I do get this warning.

The warning:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

The function within question:

```
getUserLogged = (newUser) => {
    this.setState ({
        userLogged : newUser,
        isUserLogged : true
    })
}
```

this is used within my main app

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            users:[],
            userLogged : null,
            isUserLogged: false,
            isAdmin : false,
        };
    }
```

Within my app component, I display 1 of 3 main components: OderPage, AdminPanel or LoginPanel.

If `isUserLogged` is null, we display

```
<div className="loginPrompt">
  <LoginPage getUserLogged={this.getUserLogged} users = {this.state.users} getAdminLogged = {this.getAdminLogged}/>
</div>
```

Inside my login component, I display a pin panel that the user pressed and I compare the pins to those saved in the DB.

If they match, we call `getUserLogged` :

```
if (checkPin === tempPin) {
   this.props.getUserLogged(user);
}
```

After that function is called, the main app's state changed, this rendering a new component (orderpage) and no longer rendering the old one (login).

This application. I don't see any problems in performance, but I do get this warning. Any suggestions?

**EDIT (more detail):**

The way my app component renders is it pushes the component to render into a array, displayed like so:

```
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {whichRender}
        </div>
    )
```

the if statements that use getUserLogged and login panel:

```
var whichRender = [];
if (this.state.isUserLogged) {
    whichRender.push (
        <div className="AppContainer" key={this.state.userLogged.name}>
            <MainNav user={this.state.userLogged.name} handleLogOut = {this.handleLogOut}/>
            <OrderPage user={this.state.userLogged.name} handleLogOut = {this.handleLogOut}/>     
        </div>
    )
} else {
    whichRender.push (
        <div className="AppContainer" key={'loginPromptApp'}>
            <div className="loginPrompt">
                <LoginPage getUserLogged={this.getUserLogged} users = {this.state.users} getAdminLogged = {this.getAdminLogged}/>
            </div> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it is related or just a typo, but in your getUserLogged method you have "userLogged: user," but did you mean to set it to the newUser parameter?

Comment: how do you `render()`? Provide method

Comment: Where do you have following functionality if (checkPin === tempPin) { this.props.getUserLogged(user); }. I mean in render or any life cycle method where is it placed in your component?

Comment: @Think-Twice the checking pin is inside the main render of the loginPage component. I've added some more detail in hopes that it will help